# How to add list to heapq in python

Tags: list, heapq

How can i **add the input list to heap directly?**,Where some of the inbuild function used to push,get min,extract min but how to extract the maximum from the heap.
some functions like..

1. heapify(iterable) :- This function is used to convert the iterable into a heap data structure. i.e. in heap order.
2. heappush(heap, ele) :- This function is used to insert the element mentioned in its arguments into heap. The order is adjusted, so as heap structure is maintained.
3. heappop(heap) :- This function is used to remove and return the smallest element from heap. The order is adjusted, so as heap structure is maintained.

```
heap = [] 
heapify(heap) 
heappush(heap,  10) 
heappush(heap,  30) 
heappush(heap, 20) 
heappush(heap,  400) 


# printing the elements of the heap 

for i in heap: 
    print( i, end = ' ') 
print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import heapq

heap = []   # creates an empty heap
item = [20, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9]
for i in item:
    heapq.heappush(heap, i)  # pushes a new item on the heap

print('Heap obtained from heappush() : ', heap)

heapq.heapify(item)  # transforms list into a heap, in-place, in linear time

print('Heap obtained from heapify() : ', item)
```

And for maxheap

1. *heapq* implements function with suffix *_max* example : _heapify_max, _heapreplace_max, etc.

   ```
    from _heapq import _heappop_max, _heapify_max, _heapreplace_max

    a = [20, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9]
    _heapify_max(a)

    print('Heap obtained from _heappop_max() : ', a)
   ```
2. Or you can multiple the list with -1 and use minheap itself.

   ```
    Then 100 becomes -100, 5 becomes -5, etc.
   ```

I hope this helps.